# Mac AVAudioUnitReverb Ignoring loadFactoryPreset()

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avfoundation, avaudioengine

### Original problem…

I'm working on a cross platform iOS/Mac app using AVFoundation and AVAudioEngine. The problem that I'm running into is that `AVAudioUnitReverb` seems to be ignoring the `loadFactoryPreset()` method on the Mac, but works fine in iOS.

I've isolated my problem to the following minimal amount of sample code. Pasting this into an iOS Playground results in a definitely echo-y `.plate` reverb. In a Mac playground, I get a reverb effect, but not the one I intended. It seems to be stuck with the default `.mediumHall` preset.

If you'd like to download the iOS and Mac playgrounds with the included audio file, I've uploaded them here: http://server.briantoth.com/ReverbPlayground.zip

I've tried searching for similar problems with no luck. I've tried it under 10.11, 10.12, and the latest 10.13 beta with the same results. I have to be missing something. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import AVFoundation

let sourceFile: AVAudioFile
let format: AVAudioFormat

let sourceFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixLoop", withExtension: "caf")!
sourceFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: sourceFileURL)
format = sourceFile.processingFormat

let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()

engine.attach(player)
engine.attach(reverb)

// set desired reverb parameters
reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.plate)
reverb.wetDryMix = 100

// make connections
engine.connect(player, to: reverb, format: format)
engine.connect(reverb, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)

// schedule source file
player.scheduleFile(sourceFile, at: nil)

try! engine.start()
player.play()

sleep(20)
```

---

### Update with workaround…

Further research suggests that this is a bug in the AVAudioUnitReverb class on the Mac and I'll report it to Apple as such.  If I get the parameters for the underlying audio unit with a `.mediumHall` preset applied on iOS, I get this:

```
kReverb2Param_DryWetMix: 100.0
kReverb2Param_Gain: 1.0
kReverb2Param_MinDelayTime: 0.01
kReverb2Param_MaxDelayTime: 0.07
kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz: 2.1
kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist: 1.1
kReverb2Param_RandomizeReflections: 1.0
```

On the Mac, I get this for *every single preset value*:

```
kReverb2Param_DryWetMix: 100.0
kReverb2Param_Gain: 35.0
kReverb2Param_MinDelayTime: 0.014745
kReverb2Param_MaxDelayTime: 0.0614
kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAt0Hz: 0.014925
kReverb2Param_DecayTimeAtNyquist: 0.001
kReverb2Param_RandomizeReflections: 0.655
```

On iOS, the different presets change the parameters as expected. On the Mac, there is no effect. The values don't even match the documented default of `.mediumHall`. I wonder if it has anything to do with the Mac reverb being a `kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixReverb` vs the iOS `kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2`.

If I manually configuring the underlying audio unit on the Mac myself, then the reverb works as expected. For the time being I was able to write my own `loadFactoryPreset()` to bypass the problem by setting the parameters to the iOS equivalent values for each preset.